# How to return value into the script of another Vue file? Or how to sent returned value into another Vue file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, parent-child, return-value

In the main page, I got the value I want which are "time" and "breedKey" already. Now, how can I use them in another Vue file like the example I provide next

```
   data() {
        return {
          time:[]
        }
    },

    computed: {
       breedKey() {
         return this.breeds[this.currentBreed].key;
        }
      }
```

This is the child page `<script>` that I want to pass my data(breedKey, time) into, I want to use the parameters like this. Not quite sure if the logic is too simple, or are there any better method to do it?

```
async created() {
    try {
      this.promise = axios.get(
        "https://my-api/"
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [global variable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) even tough this is not the main purpose of it in your case.

You define it somewhere with `Vue.prototype.$myvar`

And you can use it in your component like `this.$myvar`

However you should probably have a look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and the concept of store.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass them from parent to child using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

If you have to navigate you could use [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) and pass them as parts of the route and then [retrieve](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) them in the second page

If you want an even more decoupled way of communicating you could use [EventBus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) or go all the way an use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Most likely you just need to pass them as props, so declare a child that has the props declared

```
export default {
 props:['breedKey', 'time']
}
```

and then pass them

```
<ChildComp :breedKey="breedKey" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so I use the v-bind to sent data and prop to receive data in child component already, but when the value of 'breedKey', 'time" are changed in parent, prop are not update in child component, any recommendation?

Comment: How are you updating them. They should update. Do you add the keys dynamically to an object?

Comment: It fine if I just use {{breedKey}} in <template> of child page, but I use it in script part like this.breedKey, which remain the first value it get, not sure why {{breedKey}} is update but not {{this.breedKey}}

Comment: from what i test, {{ breedKey }} in template part change, but in script part which I do data() return  topic:this.breedKey    The topic is not update at all